# Spacing above align within an enumerate

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, enumerate

So I've tried `\vspace`, `\abovedisplayskip=0pt` and a few other things and nothing seems to be doing what I want. I want to make it so that the `align` is on the same line as the item. So for example the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item  \begin{align}
        \label{x bs y in -}x \backslash y \subseteq I^-\\
        \label{y bs x in +}y \backslash x \subseteq I^+
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
```

Produces:

[image: With Space]

I want it to look like

[image: No Space]

Any ideas?

Comment: Nobody will understand what the two numbers in the first line are referring to.

Comment: So then assume I used align* instead of align. I don't actually need those labels. It was just a minimal working example that showed the spacing situation. (Unless align* and align work differently?) - Although you do make a good point in case anyone wants to just 'copy' and 'paste' the code. align should probably not be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may not be a good practice, but how to do it? Here is an attempt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
    \item \leavevmode\vspace{\dimexpr-\abovedisplayskip-\baselineskip\relax}
     \begin{align}
        \label{x bs y in -}x \backslash y \subseteq I^-\\
        \label{y bs x in +}y \backslash x \subseteq I^+
    \end{align}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sweet! This works. I'll wait 1 day to see if someone comes up with a 'good practice' method (although can you explain or point to why the above is not good practive?) if nothing comes up I'll go ahead and accept your answer =D

Comment: @AramPapazian Enumerating equations is what I was referring to as not a good practice. That is why you have equation numbers.

Comment: Ah ok. The equations I'm using are more complex then the ones above and I'm showing that multiple (sets) of equations are the same, hence this syntax. Couldn't think of another way to do it.